# Disabled Radio Buttons are being displayed as selected

Tags: html, css

I was working on applying some styles on radio buttons in a form, under the normal scenario they work just fine custom styles are being applied but if I disable the radio buttons they all are being displayed as selected.

Here is my code:

```css
    input ::-ms-clear {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .radio {
      margin: 0.5rem;
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"] {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"] ~ .radio-label:before {
      content: '';
      background: white;
      border-radius: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #1c2e4f;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 1.4em;
      height: 1.4em;
      position: relative;
      top: -0.2em;
      margin-right: 1em;
      vertical-align: top;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
      -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
      transition: all 250ms ease;
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .radio-label:before {
      background-color: #3E64AD;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px white;
              box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px white;
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"]:focus ~ .radio-label:before {
      outline: none;
      border-color: #3E64AD;
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"]:disabled ~ .radio-label:before {
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px white;
              box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px white;
      border-color: #bfbfbf;
      background: #bfbfbf;
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"] ~ .radio-label:empty:before {
      margin-right: 5em;
    }
    
    .radio-label {
        line-height: 1rem;
    }
```

```html
     <div>
        <label> Radio buttons </label>
        <div class="col-md-3 radio">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="'NONE'" name="feature1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"/>
            <span class="radio-label"> OPT I </span>
          </label>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 radio">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="'NONE'" name="feature1" disabled="disabled"/>
            <span class="radio-label"> OPT II </span>
          </label>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 radio">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="'NONE'" name="feature1" disabled="disabled"/>
            <span class="radio-label"> OPT III </span>
          </label>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

without applying styles its working fine, can anyone point me where am I wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this style:

```
.radio input[type="radio"]:disabled ~ .radio-label:before {
  background: #bfbfbf;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
    input ::-ms-clear {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .radio {
      margin: 0.5rem;
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"] {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"] ~ .radio-label:before {
      content: '';
      background: white;
      border-radius: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #1c2e4f;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 1.4em;
      height: 1.4em;
      position: relative;
      top: -0.2em;
      margin-right: 1em;
      vertical-align: top;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
      -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
      transition: all 250ms ease;
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .radio-label:before {
      background-color: #3E64AD;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px white;
              box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px white;
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"]:focus ~ .radio-label:before {
      outline: none;
      border-color: #3E64AD;
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"]:disabled ~ .radio-label:before {
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px white;
              box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px white;
      border-color: #bfbfbf;
    }
    .radio input[type="radio"] ~ .radio-label:empty:before {
      margin-right: 5em;
    }
    
    .radio-label {
        line-height: 1rem;
    }
```

```html
     <div>
        <label> Radio buttons </label>
        <div class="col-md-3 radio">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="'NONE'" name="feature1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"/>
            <span class="radio-label"> OPT I </span>
          </label>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 radio">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="'NONE'" name="feature1" disabled="disabled"/>
            <span class="radio-label"> OPT II </span>
          </label>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 radio">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="'NONE'" name="feature1" disabled="disabled"/>
            <span class="radio-label"> OPT III </span>
          </label>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: But I want to show greyed out radio button for selected ones and empty ones which are not selected, removing this will make user think that radio button is enabled.

Comment: Do you want the whole *circle* greyed out instead of just the inner part of the circle?  If so, then keep the background but remove the box-shadow.

Comment: for non selected radio buttons I want it to be just a hollow greyed out circle and for selected I want to be filled greyed out circle with grey dot :)

Comment: Not sure what "hollow greyed out" would look like?

Comment: it would be like your normal un-selected radio button.

Comment: this should do it.